# Duplicated reference key - Fluent NHibernate Automapping

Tags: nhibernate, duplicates, fluent, automapping

I got a problem with automapping in fluent and reference key. Example would be that:

```
public class ConfigurationCategory
{

    public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }

    [NotNull]
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual String Icon { get; set; }       

    public virtual ConfigurationCategory Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ConfigurationCategory> Children { get; private set; }

    public ConfigurationCategory()
    {
        Children = new List<ConfigurationCategory>();

    }
}
```

Results in the following SQL-Output:

```
  CREATE TABLE "ConfigurationCategory"
  ...
  parent_id uuid,

  configurationcategory_id uuid,

  CONSTRAINT "ConfigurationCategory_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),

  CONSTRAINT fk6ccc850055890dc8 FOREIGN KEY (configurationcategory_id)
      REFERENCES "ConfigurationCategory" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT fk6ccc8500ee71b726 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
      REFERENCES "ConfigurationCategory" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Why is ConfigurationCategory duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used fluent automapping, but I would guess it is confused by the fact that you have both the Parent and the Children properties; I would guess fluent can't tell that they are both meant to be handled by the same column in the database.

You probably need to create a ClassMap and specify the key column names for both the References() and HasMany() calls.